# How do I report a bug on Launchpad when I don't know which package it affects?

Tags: bug-reporting, launchpad

How do I report a bug on Launchpad when I don't know which package it affects? I tried just reporting it directly to "Ubuntu", but "Report a Bug" on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu just redirects to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs rather than a form for filling out a bug.

In my particular case this is a bug with [a 404 link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. I have no clue in the world which package would have bugs for this configuration file.

Comment: `dpkg -S /etc/sysctl.conf` -> `procps: /etc/sysctl.conf`. The file is now  at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/sysrq.rst , btw. Which version of Ubuntu? My 16.04 `sysctl.conf` doesn't contain any links to kernel.org.

Comment: This occurs for me on 18.04.